# Fixed div is going behind flexbox when scrolling

Tags: css, flexbox, position

i'm new in "programming" websites (just for fun) and got a problem i don't find a solution for.

Code at the end or codeopen /Tisire/pen/wLRvdR

The menu button should be fixed and never hide
but when scrolling down, the menu button goes behind the flexbox

I already found similiar problems here but without a working solution for me ... flex and position seems not to be a good combination.

Anyone a idea?

Code:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

```css
/* Menu */
#topnav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
  padding-left: 1em; 
  padding-right: 1em;
  max-width: 70em;
}

#logo {
  font-size:2em;
  float:left;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

#menubutton {
  font-size:80px;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:fixed;
}

#menuright {
  float: right;
  padding-right:5em;
}

.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
}

/*Just to fill space...*/
.somespaceforthistest {
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

/*The Flexbox*/
 .flex-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
   max-width: 80em;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
 }

 .flex-container > div {
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   width: 25em;
   margin: 10px;
   height: 25em;
   position: relative;
 }
 
 img.flex {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
   <a href="#">Just</a>
   <a href="#">some</a>
   <a href="#">random</a>
   <a href="#">points</a>
    </div>
  </div>

<div id="topnav">
   <div id="logo">MyLogo</div>
   <div id="menuright">
    <div id="menubutton" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</div>
   </div>
  </div>

<div class="somespaceforthistest">
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
    <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>  
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
   <div>6</div>  
   <div>7</div>
   <div>8</div>
   <div>9</div>  
   <div>10</div>
   <div>11</div>
   <div>12</div>  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index: 1;` to your `#menubutton`

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67neyb2d/)

Answer (score 1):

just add z-index property to your button

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

```css
/* Menu */
#topnav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
  padding-left: 1em; 
  padding-right: 1em;
  max-width: 70em;
}

#logo {
  font-size:2em;
  float:left;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

#menubutton {
  font-size:80px;
  cursor:pointer;
 z-index:3;
  position:fixed;
}

#menuright {
  float: right;
  padding-right:5em;
}

.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
}

/*Just to fill space...*/
.somespaceforthistest {
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

/*The Flexbox*/
 .flex-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
   max-width: 80em;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
 }

 .flex-container > div {
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   width: 25em;
   margin: 10px;
   height: 25em;
   position: relative;
 }
 
 img.flex {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
   <a href="#">Just</a>
   <a href="#">some</a>
   <a href="#">random</a>
   <a href="#">points</a>
    </div>
  </div>

<div id="topnav">
   <div id="logo">MyLogo</div>
   <div id="menuright">
    <div id="menubutton" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</div>
   </div>
  </div>

<div class="somespaceforthistest">
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
  Just some Text to fill space...<br>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
    <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>  
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
   <div>6</div>  
   <div>7</div>
   <div>8</div>
   <div>9</div>  
   <div>10</div>
   <div>11</div>
   <div>12</div>  
 </div>
```